# I want to avoid that the function GetListCsvFiles () returns a null, when there is no file in the directory

Tags: c#, null

I want to avoid that the function `GetListCsvFiles ()` returns a null, when there is no file in the directory.

I can add a test, but I want to avoid if possible.

```
using System;
using NLog;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {

        private static Logger report = LogManager.GetLogger("EventReport");

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            report.Info("Start Program");
            EveryQuotesDB everyQuotesDB = new EveryQuotesDB();
            //string[] csvFiles = everyQuotesDB.GetListCsvFiles(@"C:\DirectoryCsvFiles");
            string[] csvFiles = everyQuotesDB.GetListCsvFiles(@"C:\DirectoryEmpty");

                foreach (string file in csvFiles)
                {
                    report.Info(file);
                };

            report.Info("End Program");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
}



using System.IO;
using NLog;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
   class EveryQuotesDB
    {
        private static Logger report = LogManager.GetLogger("EventReport");

        public string[] GetListCsvFiles(string directoryCsvFiles)
        {
            string[] csvFiles = null;

            try
            {
                csvFiles = Directory.GetFiles(directoryCsvFiles, "*.csv");
            }
            catch (DirectoryNotFoundException)
            {
                report.Fatal("Directory Not Found : " + directoryCsvFiles);
            }

            return csvFiles;
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Well, what do you want it to return?  An empty array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this line:

```
string[] csvFiles = null;
```

with this:

```
string[] csvFiles = new string[0];
```

That will make the default value an empty string array instead of null.

Comment: Tanks. 
Easy to understand.
Solve the question from the start.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

instead of

```
return csvFiles;
```

do

```
return csvFiles ?? new string[0];
```

The ?? is check if the dsvFiles not null then return it otherwise return an empty array.

Comment: Tanks.
Answered the fastest ?.
Slight preference for the answer of recursive.